# How to Sqoop import tables table1, table2, table3?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, bigdata

one of employer asking how to Sqoop import table 1 and table 2, table 3 in single database, and multiple database?

Comment: but do you mean general algorithm or syntax how to run commands?

Comment: yes i need a command with example please

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

1. Multiple tables: try to use "import-all-tables" and comma separated "exclude-tables" option:

> sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoop
>   --username root --password hadoop  --target-dir '/sqoop'  --exclude-tables table1,table2

2. Multiple tables: in Sqoop 1.99 there is an option for executing custom SQL query - you can check if you can import/export multiple tables

> [check documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.7/user/connectors/Connector-GenericJDBC.html)

3. Multiple databases:

> I don't know if there is any command for multiple JDBC connections,
>   but I would try to implement simple bash script to run "sqoop-import"
>   with multiple connections - only setting "connect" option properly